# dealing with lots of collision

Tags: iphone

What would be the best way to go about adding collision to my application. Right now I have a lot of jagged walls and a couple of weird shapes that I wanna make collision for but am not sure which is the right path to get the job done. What would you guys do if you had a room full of walls with different shapes and sizes that needed collision implemented ?

Comment: I realise this question is now a year old but it might be worth migrating it to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would read a set of articles on collision detection. Paul Nettle used to [write about the topic](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1026.asp) ([PDF](http://www.paulnettle.com/pub/FluidStudios/CollisionDetection/Fluid_Studios_Generic_Collision_Detection_for_Games_Using_Ellipsoids.pdf)) and has [a nice library](http://www.paulnettle.com/pub/FluidStudios/CollisionDetection/) for free.

> This document will describe a
>   collision technique that allows you to
>   move an ellipsoid (a sphere with three
>   different radii, one for each axis)
>   through a world that not only properly
>   detects collisions, but also reacts in
>   a way that gamers would expect from
>   the common first person shooter.
>
> This technique also allows for sliding
>   along surfaces as well as easy
>   implementation of gravity, which
>   includes sliding downhill when
>   standing stationary. This technique
>   also allows automatic climbing of
>   stairs and sliding over bumps in walls
>   (like door frames) and any other
>   randomly oriented “stair-like
>   topography”.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Chipmunk physics engine](http://wiki.slembcke.net/main/published/Chipmunk), which has a very good physics + collisions.

Or even [Cocos2d-iphone](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/) library - 2d game engine with Chipmunk inside. [Here are examples](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/wiki/GamesUsingCocos2d) of games, created with it.